# Install error for GIMP 2.8 repository in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: gimp, add-apt-repository

Hi I'm a linux newbie and am having some problems with installing Gimp 2.8.  I previously installed Gimp 2.6 onto my 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 machine using Ubuntu Software Center.  However, I recently tried out 2.8 and found that I like the changes and would like to install this version instead.  So, I looked up how to install and tried the following method:

Uninstalled Gimp 2.6 using the following methods:

1) Uninstalled using Software Center (and uninstalled all add-ons)

I have tried the following command-line actions as well:

```
$sudo apt-get remove gimp
$sudo apt-get autoremove gimp gimp-plugin-registry
$sudo apt-get purge gimp*
```

It uninstalled fine, and was no longer listed as installed in Software Center.

Then I tried the standard method to install Gimp via terminal:

```
$sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
$sudo apt-get update
$sudo apt-get install gimp
```

This worked perfectly on my laptop, which now has Gimp 2.8 installed and working great.  However, on my desktop I ran into a problem at the first stage of trying to add the repository.

Upon the first step ("    $sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp"), I get the following error message in terminal:

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
[sudo] password for daniel: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/add-apt-repository", line 8, in <module>
    from softwareproperties.SoftwareProperties import SoftwareProperties, expand_shortcut_line
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/SoftwareProperties.py", line 53, in <module>
    from ppa import AddPPASigningKeyThread, expand_ppa_line
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/softwareproperties/ppa.py", line 31, in <module>
    import pycurl
ImportError: libheimbase.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

And then when I carry out the rest of the actions via terminal it installs the 2.6 version of Gimp.

Both computers are running 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.  I did look into the libheimbase.so.1 file listed a bit (it is in the /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu directory) and it seems like it is absent from my Desktop (which is the one having the problems) but present on my laptop.

I don't know exactly why this problem exists, as I generally try to keep the two systems pretty similar- but it's possible I accidentally uninstalled/removed this file on my Desktop (or never installed it).

Anyway, I was wondering what exactly is happening and how I can possibly fix this so I can install the Gimp repository (and thus Gimp 2.8) on my Desktop?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So, in case anyone else runs into this problem, I figured out how to fix this.  It was actually a problem with the `apt-get-repository` package itself, rather than something to do with gimp.  So I'm thinking I must have removed the above mentioned libheimbase.so.1 file while uninstalling something else, since this seems to be a shared file/library.  So I looked up the origins of this file and it's part of the package: [libheimbase1-heimdal](http://packages.ubuntu.com/uk/precise/amd64/libheimbase1-heimdal/filelist)

So I installed/reinstalled this package:

```
sudo apt-get install libheimbase1-heimdal --reinstall
```

Then did the normal actions for installing the repository and gimp.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:otto-kesselgulasch/gimp
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install gimp
```

and everything is working perfectly now!